# How do I query a BigMap using Netezos?

Tags: bigmap

I would like to query a BigMap using Netezos, for instance to get the only element of https://ghostnet.tzkt.io/KT1FpoA4yVSyRHwWzycRLXgbC7o8ecRsYz55/storage/254861

I'm guessing this page should help, but it's a bit hard for me to go from this to an actual well-formed request: https://github.com/baking-bad/netezos/blob/cd1383e525345fc79cfc533f8f93f62519556624/Netezos/Rpc/Queries/Post/BigMapQuery.cs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was kindly answered on the Netezos support chat on Discord.

The first answer was to simply use the tzkt API, I won't detail that part because it's well documented.

The second answer was given through this example. As you can see, the type of the bigmap is needed which can be a bit cumbersome unless it is generated automatically.

```
var bigmap = Micheline.FromJson("""
{
    "prim": "big_map",
    "args": [
        {
            "prim": "address"
        },
        {
            "prim": "pair",
            "args": [
                {
                    "prim": "nat"
                },
                {
                    "prim": "map",
                    "args": [
                        {
                            "prim": "address"
                        },
                        {
                            "prim": "nat"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
""");

var key = Micheline.FromJson("""
{
    "string": "tz1fSkEwBCgTLas8Y82SYpEGW9aFZPBag8uY"
}
""");

var schema = new BigMapSchema(bigmap as MichelinePrim);

var bigmapId = 123;
var keyHash = schema.GetKeyHash(key);
// exprv6M7FDjZNicPYmt588PCJNNk22MWUSjru5jbxxZQR11NLfCwkz

var value = await rpc.Blocks.Head.Context.BigMaps[bigmapId][keyHash].GetAsync();
```